# Concrete5.6.4.0 CMS Custom made multiple file upload form

Tags: file-upload, concrete5

I develop websites using an older version of Concrete5 which sadly uses Flash to upload files in bulk to its File Manager. Can this be done using a basic php form with an multiple upload facility that dumps the files in the File Manager and still 'readable' through the CMS dashboard? I know how to build the form with single file uploads but unsure how to allow multiple (up to 10 photos) and send them to the directory on the server.
Any ideas please? Or references I should check out?

Comment: Which c5 version?

Comment: Concrete5.6.4.0

Comment: This version has an option to upload multiple files from the file manager. Can't you use this functionality? Otherwise you would need to write a lot of code.. Collect all selected files by javascript and send the parameter to the server, where it has to be validated and transformed the files into c5-files. Then maybe you get a server timeout. You would need to handle the right amount of files.

Comment: As I said in the original question the multiple file upload is driven by Flash which will be phased out of browser hence the need for another option. I can upload files to the server but need it to be processed by C5 File Manager.